# ghostScript with Node generates fatal error

Tags: node.js, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using ghostscript with Node (running on MacOX and Ubuntu).  my ghostscript command is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=output.pdf -dBATCH input1.pdf input2.pdf
```

When I run this command manually, it works.  When it's kicked off by NodeJS, I get this error:

```
[2014-09-08 10:33:20.587] [INFO] console - { [Error: Command failed: GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
Error: Command failed: GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:647:15)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:966:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Node code looks like this:

```
var execCommand = config.ghostScript + " -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=" + finalFileName + " -dBATCH " + inputFiles;
exec(execCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if ( error !== null ) {
        var err = new Error("pdf could not be generated");
        err.status = constants.HTTPCODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that your problem with the inputFiles in the manual way there are spaces between the input files, but through NodeJS you will have to loop around the inputfiles and separate each with a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that user1283633 is correct. In any event you should first print out what's in your 'exec' variable and see if its what you expect. 9 times out of 10 when people say 'this command line works, but when I put it in my program it doesn't' it turns out that what's being generated by their application isn't the same command line.

You should also capture stdout and stderr from Ghostscript (if nothing else you can redirect them to files). Ghostscript is undoubtedly printing more information about the problem, and you are simply discarding it.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to use Ghostscript4JS, it's a module that binds the Ghostscript C command API to bring its power to the Node.JS world.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ghostscript4js

Ghostscript4JS is a native Node.JS addon so you can call the C command Ghostscript API directly from your JavaScript code. In this way you have two benefits:

1. Better error handling:
   You directly intercept the error through the try/catch for the sync method and then/catch promise for the async method.
2. Performance
   The call to the shell command takes more time and more resources than the     call to the C or C++ API directly from Node.js environment.

As programmer you have more control against call external tool.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Link-only answers are not helpful, especially if the link should break.  Please provide the important aspects to your answer here, and provide links for reference.